# Can i set frame on video with GPUImage?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avfoundation, video-processing, gpuimage

I have one local video file, Now i have applied filters with help of GPUImage library,
here is code to make filtered video with GPUImage

```
movieFile = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:sampleURL];
pixellateFilter = [[GPUImagePixellateFilter alloc] init];
GPUImageRotationFilter *rotationFilter = [[GPUImageRotationFilter alloc] initWithRotation:kGPUImageRotateRight];

[movieFile addTarget:rotationFilter];
[rotationFilter addTarget:pixellateFilter];

NSString *pathToMovie = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Movie.m4v"];
unlink([pathToMovie UTF8String]);
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToMovie];

movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:movieURL size:CGSizeMake(480.0, 640.0)];
[pixellateFilter addTarget:movieWriter];

[movieWriter startRecording];
[movieFile startProcessing];

[pixellateFilter removeTarget:movieWriter];
[movieWriter finishRecording];
```

Now i want to apply frame on this video file, i mean i have fetch naturalSize of video file. And want to apply frame with naturalSize on this video file.

How can i do ? Is it possible ?

Regards,

******** Solved *********
Add image on video that's not possible with GPUImage as per my limit..
many thanks to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377917/can-i-add-uiimage-or-cgimageref-to-video/11395787#11395787)

Comment: Not possible with GPUImage, i have used AVFoundation  framework and done...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377917/can-i-add-uiimage-or-cgimageref-to-video/11395787#11395787

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can fetch natural Size of video file by following code.. by @mayur-shrivas
as per [GPUImage : Apply filer to existing video file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332390/gpuimage-apply-filer-to-existing-video-file)

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURLNSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToMovie] options:nil];
AVAssetTrack *videoAssetTrack = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:movieURL size:CGSizeMake(videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.width, videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.height)];
```