# GPUImage : Apply filer to existing video file

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I was trying to use video filters of `GPUImage` framework. I followed [Filtering and re-encoding a movie](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2012/02/12/introducing-gpuimage-framework) tutorial. It giving me error `Unknown type name GPUImageRotationFilter`. So i tried to apply a simple filter to my video file

Here is my code
**viewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<GPUImageMovieWriterDelegate,GPUImageInput>
{
GPUImageMovie *_movieFile;
GPUImageOutput<GPUImageInput> *_sketchFilter;
GPUImageMovieWriter *_movieWriter;

}
 @property (nonatomic,retain)    GPUImageMovie *movieFile; 
 @property (nonatomic,retain)    GPUImageOutput<GPUImageInput> *sketchFilter; 
 @property (nonatomic,retain)    GPUImageMovieWriter *movieWriter;
@end
```

**viewController.m**

```
NSURL *sampleURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"sample_iPod" withExtension:@"m4v"];

self.movieFile = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:sampleURL];
self.sketchFilter = [[GPUImageSketchFilter alloc] init];
[self.movieFile addTarget:self.sketchFilter];


NSString *pathToMovie = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Movie.m4v"];
unlink([pathToMovie UTF8String]);
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToMovie];

self.movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:movieURL size:CGSizeMake(480.0, 640.0)];
[self.sketchFilter addTarget:self.movieWriter];

[self.movieWriter startRecording];
[self.movieFile startProcessing];

[self.movieWriter setCompletionBlock:^{

    [self.sketchFilter removeTarget:self.movieWriter];
    [self.movieWriter finishRecording];

}];
```

This one also giving me **BAD_ACCESS**.

**Stack trace**

[image]

1. What Iam doing wrong?
2. Can any explain me how to apply GPUImage filter to an existing video file?.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Where are you getting the EXC_BAD_ACCESS? How did you define movieFile, sketchFilter and movieWriter? The GPUImageRotationFilter is an old filter which isn't available anymore, you should be using the GPUImageTransformFilter instead.

Comment: @TomasCamin I cant figure out where iam getting bad access. See my updated question

Comment: Does your project use ARC? What iOS version are you targeting?

Comment: Iam not using ARC. Deployment target ios6.0

Comment: First, that post of mine you're referring to above was simply the original Readme.md for the GPUImage project, which is well out of date at this point. Follow the Readme instructions from GitHub for the latest way to set this up. Second, use the SimpleVideoFileFilter example as a basis. Your code above should work fine, and does in that sample application on my test device with the latest version of the framework.

Answer (score 0):

First of all update your `GPUImageFramework` with the latest one. You can get the new one from [here](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage).

Double check the size of the moviewWriter. It should be `CGSizeMake(640.0, 480.0)` instead of `CGSizeMake(480.0, 640.0)`.

Or you can create an video asset and then provide the size of video asset in the size parameter.

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURLNSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToMovie] options:nil];
AVAssetTrack *videoAssetTrack = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:movieURL size:CGSizeMake(videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.width, videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.height)];
```

Its working for me.